# Types static constructor calling

Tags: c#, static, constructor, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't the CLR always call value type constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246078/why-doesnt-the-clr-always-call-value-type-constructors)

Found next code in Richter's book (I have simplified it a little bit):

```
internal struct SomeValType
{
    static SomeValType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This never gets displayed");
    }
    public Int32 X;
}

public sealed class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SomeValType a = new SomeValType { X = 123 };
        Console.WriteLine(a.X);
    }
}
```

Output:

> 123

Can't understand why `WriteLine` in static constructor nevel calls. Looked at ILDasm - constructor code and calling of method are present. If I add any static variable to `SomeValType` and init it in constructor then `WriteLine` calling correctly.

Can someone explain, please, behavior in such situation? Thanks.

Comment: I tried making X static and assigning it in the constructor. This made the console output appear as expected. Same thing happened if I removed X entirely and threw in a static method that I called in Main(). Perhaps static constructors aren't invoked unless a static method or member is called/accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you're never accessing a *real* constructor nor a static field.

The default constructor of value types is special. It's just an initialization to binary the default value of all fields(i.e. binary zero the whole struct)

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

- A static constructor is called
  automatically to initialize the **class** [emphasis mine]
  before the first instance is created
  or any static members are referenced.

It seems that the word class is the key here. Making SomeValType a class results in a static constructor invocation upon creating the first instance of the type as stated above. When it is a struct, however, it seems you need to access a static field or call a static method for this behavior to be triggered. Is this a bug or is it intended?